# Ember-appkit-rails sprockets NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, rubygems

I've installed ember-appkit-rails, but when I do rails g ember:bootstrap I get the following error can anyone help?

/home/ltsimps/.rvm/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/ember-appkit-rails-0.3.0/lib/ember/appkit/rails/sprockets/context.rb:10:in '': undefined method prepend' for Sprockets::Context:Class (NoMethodError)
from /home/ltsimps/.rvm/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in 'require' 
from /home/ltsimps/.rvm/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228 'block in require'
from /home/ltsimps/.rvm/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213 'load_dependency'

from /home/ltsimps/.rvm/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228 'require'

from /home/ltsimps/.rvm/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/ember-appkit-rails-0.3.0/lib/ember/appkit/rails/sprockets.rb:3:in  ....

Answer (score 1):

I just changed to ruby 2.0 and that fixed the problem.

Comment: This worked for me. I also got `ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault` until I ran `bundle exec rails g ember:bootstrap` (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895007/segmentation-fault-with-ruby-2-0-0p247-leading-to-rails-server-crashing).